# Can I move HVAC register to bay on the left?

Tags: hvac

I'd like to move register to the bay of the left. What kind of elbows can I use so that duct can go through the stud? If there is no such elbow, what are my options?

[image: Photo of register]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't remove the entire depth of a stud without building a header over the opening, which must be adequate to carry any load above. If you're willing to do that...

Two oval duct elbows will get you to the same outlet box, which will be flipped over to have top-inlet. Easy peasy.

```
  |  |       header (supported by trimmer studs)      |  |
  |  |________________________________________________|  |
  |  |  |      ______________________________      |  |  |
  |  |  |     /                               \    |  |  |
  |  |  |    |                                 |   |  |  |
  |  |  |    |        _______________          |   |  |  |
  |  |  | ___|________|___    __      \        |   |  |  |
  |  |  ||                |  |  |     |        |   |  |  |
  |  |  ||                |  |  |     |        |   |  |  |
  |  |  ||                |  |  |     |        |   |  |  |
  |  |  ||________________|  |  |     |        |   |  |  |
  |  |  |                    |  |     |        |   |  |  |
__|__|__|____________________|__|_____|        |___|__|__|___
______________________________________|        |_____________
                              ^
                          floated stud for drywall backing
```

[image]